# Google Play Games: 401 error on UnlockAchievement call

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I've implemented Google Play Services with this asset: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity.

I've added Saved Games and Achievements, but looks like achievements don't work properly. It works on my dev device, but o production I see 100% errors:

[image: Screenshot]

It looks like it works normally, when achievement unlocked, users see alert from Google Play Games, but after all the can't see achievements in Play Games application. Also we see that nobody unlocked some achievements when I look to the Play Console:

[image: Console screenshot]

As I understand it's the problem with authorization, I've doeble-checked that I setup OAUTH key correctly, using the same SHA-1 as SHA-1 fingerprint of my sign key.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2358?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I used Upload key certificate instead of App signing key certificate. Official docs recommends keytool utility for extracting sha-1 from your keystore, but if you use Play App Signing - it doesn't make sense. You should use sha-1 from Google Play Console -> Setup -> App Signing -> App signing key (or check that Google Cloud Console has already client with right sha-1).

NOTE: you can also use client for Upload key for local testing.

NOTE-2: errors will start to disappear in Google Cloud Console immediately, but achievements will appear in Google Play Console only after 3 days.